# How to execute a dynamically generated R command

Tags: r, bioconductor, sbml

I have a [SBML file](http://1drv.ms/1LmEXRs) which contains details of series of biochemical reactions. Each reaction has a set of reactants (metabolites). My goal is to get a list of reactants for each of the reactions. I can manually access the list of reactants as follows.

```
library(SBMLR)
currentFile = readSBML("Sample.xml")
currentReactants = currentFile$reactions$R_DM_4CRSOL$reactants
```

Here **R_DM_4CRSOL** is the name of the first reaction. And each time when I want to get the list of reactants I need to specify the reactionID. But the thing is I have 2700 reactions and I need to automate the process. I tried assigning the ReactioinID into a variable and executing the command as follows. But it doesn't work as follows.

```
a = "R_DM_4CRSOL"
b = currentFile$reactions$a$reactants
```

Finally I thought of creating a string of the executable command for each of the reaction. I was able to create the string but I don't know how to execute it. I tried using sys but it gives me a warning as follows.

```
a = "$R_DM_4CRSOL"
b = paste("currentFile$reactions",a,"$reactants",sep="")
d = system(b)
```

> Warning message: running command
>   'currentFile$reactions$R_DM_4CRSOL$reactants' had status 127

Can someone please tell me how can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `eval(parse(text=b))`

Comment: Although `currentFile$reactions[["R_DM_4CRSOL"]]$reactants` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The second option was easy to use.